# Loop over function that has three arguments, mapply/sapply/for loops not working?

Tags: r, lapply, sapply, mapply

I am trying to loop over a function that has three arguments, but neither `lapply` nor `mapply` is providing the right solution. The goal here is to obtain all possible results based on all possible combinations of the three arguments (`num`, `resp`, `cdr`). If you see the function below, the goal here is to calculate `n` for all three levels of num (holding `resp` and `cdr` constant), for all three levels of `resp` (holding `num` and `cdr` constant), and for all three levels of `cdr` (holding `resp` and `num` constant). But as you can see from the outputs, neither `lapply` nor `mapply` are providing the right answers here.

Tried to do this with nested `for` loops with no success either (though I'm not that great on using loops, so I'm open to a loop-based solution if it gets me the right answer).

Minimally reproducible example:

```
set.seed(124)
num <- c(10, 20, 30)
resp <- sample(100:200, 3)
cdr <- 3:5

my_fun <- function(num, resp, cdr){
 n <- ((num * resp) / cdr)   
}  

sapply(num, my_fun, resp, cdr)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  360  720 1080
[2,]  350  700 1050
[3,]  302  604  906

mapply(my_fun, num, resp, cdr)
[1] 360 700 906
```

Comment: Perhaps `expand.grid(num, resp, cdr)`?

Comment: @H1 ran `expand.grid(num, resp, cdr)` but as far as I can tell it does not apply the function to obtain a calculation of `n` for each of the 27 combinations?

Comment: @rowbust I'm not sure what your expected output is supposed to be (e.g. a 3d `array`, a flattened `data.frame`, ...?). Can you edit your post to include that?

Comment: @H1 simply meant that `expand.grid()` would give you all 27 combinations, on which you could then use `mapply` (or something equivalent) properly.

Comment: @rowbust BTW Make sure your function returns something.

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
df <- expand.grid(data.frame(num, resp, cdr))
with(df, (num * resp) / cdr)

   num resp cdr         n
1   10  151   3  503.3333
2   20  151   3 1006.6667
3   30  151   3 1510.0000
4   10  176   3  586.6667
5   20  176   3 1173.3333
...
```

Comment: This seems also working `do.call(my_fun, expand.grid(data.frame(num, resp, cdr)))` +1

Answer (score 2):

A purrr/dplyr based solution would be:

```
set.seed(124)
num <- c(10, 20, 30)
resp <- sample(100:200, 3)
cdr <- 3:5

my_fun <- function(num, resp, cdr){
 ((num * resp) / cdr)   
} 

args <- list(num = num, resp = resp, cdr = cdr)
args %>% 
  purrr::cross_df() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(res = my_fun(num, resp, cdr))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# gen data
set.seed(124)
num  <- c(10, 20, 30)
resp <- sample(100:200, 3)
cdr  <- 3:5

# function (written with one input vector)
my_fun <- function(x){
  x[1] * x[2] / x[3]  
} 

# used expand.grid() and apply() to 
# eval function on all combos of num, resp, cdr
opts <- expand.grid(num, resp, cdr)
res  <- apply(opts, 1, my_fun)
cbind(opts, res)
```

Comment: `apply` seems to be not a good option because OP's function is vectorized in its arguments.

Comment: Then just:  `opts <- expand.grid(num, resp, cdr); my_fun(opts[1], opts[2], opts[3])` with the OP's definition of `my_fun`.

Comment: Yes! Check out `do.call` - very useful (and efficient) in such cases.

Comment: Yes -- frankly, despite my post, I like @markus' solution with `do.call()` best